# Change in application configuration without application restart

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, configuration-files

I have following issue: I'm introducing new feature into application (run as Windows Service) and I would like to have that new feature controlled (on/off) using some kind of configuration file entry (**myKey**). I can store config entry in app.config but if I want to change it from on->off or otherwise it would require to restart Windows Service, and I want to avoid it. I want my application to run and pick up changes in configuration.

The question is: is there a build in mechanism in .NET that addresses that problem ? I guess I could create my own config file, then use `FileSystemWatcher` etc... But perhaps .NET allows to use external config files and will reload value ??

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]
```

Thanks, Pawel

EDIT 1: Thanks for replies. However I wrote following snippet and it doesn't work (I tried creating **appSettingSection** in both places: before and inside loop):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    // AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
        AppSettingsSection appSettingSection = (AppSettingsSection)config.GetSection("appSettings");
        string myConfigData = appSettingSection.Settings["myConfigData"].Value; // still the same value, doesn't get updated
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Using GetSection(string).");
        Console.WriteLine("AppSettings section:");
        Console.WriteLine(
          appSettingSection.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()); // also XML is still the same
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I manually edit config file when application stops on **Console.ReadLine()**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once the original app.config file is loaded, it's values are cached so as you know, you'll have to restart the app. The way around this is to create a new config object and read the keys manually like this:

```
var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string myConfigData = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["myConfigData"].Value;
```

Comment: Thanks! But still: that way every time when I access myConfigData I would have to create new config object in order to be sure that appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["myConfigData"].Value is consistent with underlying value in app.config file?

Comment: Just call `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");` before you call `appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["myConfigData"].Value;` which will force the application to read the new & changed settings. Otherwise, `ConfigurationManager` inherently caches all values.

Comment: @TeomanSoygul `RefreshSection`call updates value retrieved through the `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[]` it does not affect a Configuration instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you process the configuration manually (perhaps not even in the app.config file), then you can periodically check that file for updates.

`FileSystemWatcher` is... probably overkill, and isn't guaranteed in all scenarios. Personally, I'd just poll the file every (say) 30 seconds.

Comment: Hi, do you mean pooling using solution described by @Teoman Soygul. I thing reloading that setting every 1 minute would satisfy my needs.

Comment: @dragonfly well, sort of; although I might not necessarily use the app-config path for it. Any route will work though; this doesn't need to be complex.

Answer (score 0):

Simply refresh the "appSettings" from current config file before you read the value:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings"); // Reload app settings from config file
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];          // Read the value as usually
```

No need to over complicate it by creating another config or configuration or what so ever suggested in your question or other answers!